# Create a guest with kvmtool

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, embedded-system

I want to boot a standalone application (I have the .elf file) on a KVM guest in an UltraScale platform. I am new with KVM and I'm using `kvmtool`, but I don't know how can I run a guest running my elf application.

I have read that the steps are the following:

1. `lkvm setup default` --> This creates rootfs in /home/root/.lkvm/default
2. `lkvm run -d default` --> I get an error here, there is no bzImage, but I think it should have been created automatically
3. `lkvm run -k bzImage` --> I'm not sure if I can use my .elf here instead of the bzImage to run a standalone application.

I would appreciate any help.